# S#arp Architecture

Tags: c#, asp.net, s#arp-architecture

Can someone share their experiences with s#arp architecture. we have decided to follow mvp pattern for the project. Is this okay to go with it ? The size of the project is medium. we are going to follow the tdd and ddd.

Can anybody explain how to use this architecture means explain about the layers. we don't have enough time to go through with entire documentation. if anybody expalin particle with small example in short.

please help me out!!!

Thanks,
Milind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [S#arp Architecture](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/) combines ASP.NET MVC with other frameworks and tools like

- [NHibernate](http://www.nhibernate.org/) 2.0.1
- NHibernate.Validator
- [Fluent NHibernate](http://fluentnhibernate.org/) and
- [Castle Windsor](http://www.castleproject.org/container/index.html) (IoC).

It also makes use of the [T4 templating engine](http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx) of Visual Studio to create view scaffolds.
So you could also ask yourself whether you would like to use these tools, libraries and frameworks in your project.

Frankly, if you don't have the time to read the S#arp documentation, then building a project on top of it is probably not a good idea.
One could also say the S#arp arch doesn't hide the complexity of each of the above library and framework from you, so you have to be prepared to look into each of these as well.

The S#arp documentation and the enclosing sample app explains the purpose and structure of the different layers quite well.

Answer (score 5):

The [S#arp Architecture](http://code.google.com/p/sharp-architecture/) project home page links to an active [discussion group](http://groups.google.com/group/sharp-architecture). I suggest you browse the group messages and ask any questions you have there.

Answer (score 1):

S#arp Architecture is a neat combination of some other neat tools, but you **really** need to take the time to go through the documentation and some examples.  The time you spend reading and learning is a lot less than the time you'll spend refactoring and bug-fixing if you don't study.