# Microsoft alternative to S#arp Architecture and underlying technologies

Tags: c#, s#arp-architecture

As [stated in another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792733/sarp-architecture) S#arp Architecture combines ASP.NET MVC with other frameworks and tools like

- NHibernate 2.0.1
- NHibernate.Validator
- Fluent NHibernate
- Castle Windsor
- Rhino Mocks

I understand that it is less of a framework, and more of a set of best practices, supporting DDD and encouraging TDD in every stage of the process.

However, all the tools and frameworks S#arp is based on, are third-party products, supported by the community. Even though I question neither the quality of these products, nor the commitment of the people supporting them, it would be interesting to see if Microsoft will be offering an alternative to this approach.

I understand that EF v4.0 will manage to cover most of the shortcomings of its previous releases and that MVC will get updated to its next version, but still, this is far from the comprehensive solution offered by S#arp and its components.

So, what about Microsoft's answer to the S#arp Architecture?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**NHibernate 2.0.1**
Linq to Sql (now redundent as it's been replaced with [Linq to Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386964.aspx))

**NHibernate.Validator**
There's no official equivalent. ASP.NET MVC 2.0 has [validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/07/31/asp-net-mvc-v2-preview-1-released.aspx) (look for *DataAnnotation Validation Support*), and [ValidationAspects](http://validationaspects.codeplex.com/) works with Unity.

Update: infact [DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) aren't a MVC thing but part of System.ComponentModel introduced in 3.5 SP1.

**Fluent NHibernate**
Not needed, as the Linq to SQL XML and code behind is generated by the designer.

**Castle Windsor**
[Microsoft Unity](http://www.codeplex.com/unity/)

**Rhino Mocks**
Microsoft doesn't have a mocking engine, although [MOQ](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) is produced by a Microsoft MVP.

Comment: A complete answer indeed :) Although I would say that the Entity Framework is the NHibernate alternative. Linq to Entities is a great facilitator for accessing and querying those Entities, something that isn't yet officially supported by NHibernate

Comment: As a side note, "Microsoft MVP" is not necessarily a person associated with Microsoft in any way other than being an expert in some MS technology and recognized as such by MS itself.

Comment: @Pavel that's true, although projects written by MVPs are generally closer to "what would Microsoft do" than messy, clique ports of Java projects like a lot of projects in .NET

Comment: For Fluent NHibernate, MS have their own thing called Code-Only, see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694297/does-entity-framework-4-0-allow-to-work-without-designers

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has the [Web Client Software Factory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264518.aspx) which is produced by the Patterns and Practices team at Microsoft.

[alt text http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Bb264518.wcsf_corechallenges(en-us,MSDN.10).gif](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/Bb264518.wcsf_corechallenges(en-us,MSDN.10).gif)

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft provides [The Unity Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd140117.aspx) for a dependency injection container if you are looking for the Microsoft alternative to the Castle Windsor container.